# Do any successful draft formats exist for Android: Netrunner?

Tags: android-netrunner

It's still early enough in Android: Netrunner's lifecycle that using the full cardlist to build decks isn't too overwhelming, but as time goes on, it could well be, and archetypes will become increasingly prevalent.

So, I like the idea of a draft-based game, in which I show up without a deck and build one on the spot. I think it would be really fun and probably improve my deck-building technique.

Being asymmetrical, there would be complications (you'd have to do two drafts) and there are other obstacles like influence and identities.

With that in mind, **are there any Android: Netrunner draft formats that people have tried and have found successful?**

(Bonus marks for formats that can work with as few as two players)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FFG has now released an [official draft format](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_news.asp?eidn=4673).

To participate in draft play, each player needs two components:

- A **draft starter pack**, which is a fixed set of cards (Armitage Codebusting, Crypsis, PAD Campaign, Priority Requisition, special draft identities). These cards are "private" to each player, and can be reused for multiple drafts.
- A **draft pack**, which contains a random selection of 40 cards of either runner or corp. In order to draft for both sides, a draft pack for each side is needed. These are the cards used for the draft. Draft packs are not indended to be reused, but the cards are legal for normal play unless otherwise noted.

The draft is done in 4 rounds of 10 cards each. Each round, each player starts with the top 10 cards of their draft pack. If drafting both sides, draft Corp decks first. After drafting, each player adds their draft starter pack to their pool of cards available for deckbuilding.

There are a few rules differences between draft play and normal play:

- All players use the special draft identities, which are both neutral with a 30 card deck limit and unlimited influence. The Corp identity can use agendas from all factions.
- Decks may include any number of copies of each card, instead of the normal maximum of 3 copies per card.
- Games are played to 6 Agenda Points instead of the normal 7.

An informal introduction video can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmvgsZaHEAM).

Answer (score 2):

I had this idea a few weeks ago and went looking for an answer. I found one that a friend and I tried that could be used with as few as two players, but also has the ability to scale to more. I lay this version out below. I also found one on [StimHack](http://stimhack.com/drafting-with-netrunner/) but haven't tried yet; this ones also looks good, so it's probably worth experimenting. The only downside of the StimHack format is that it is written specifically for 4 players.

### For as Few as Two Players

I found this out in a [thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/877276/netrunner-draft) on Board Game Geek. A friend and I tried it with just the two of us and it worked reasonably well. I'll outline the basics of setting this up, but read the OP and comments for a fuller understanding.

1. Start with one core set per two players
2. Take out all Identity, Private Security Force and Priority Registration cards and set them aside
3. Shuffle the Runner and Corporation cards separately, then take out 1 random Runner card and 14 random Corp cards (this should leave you with 110 each of Runner and Corp cards per two players)
4. Divide the remaining cards into packs of 11 cards each, continuing to keep the Runner and Corporation separate. With two players, this should give you ten packs for each side (note that the OP says these packs could be different sizes as long as they're evenly sized and there are the same number for Runner and Corp)
5. Split the packs evenly, with each player taking half the Runner packs and half the Corp packs
6. Start drafting! Make sure that you are drafting different sides. If Alice starts by drafting Runner, Bob should start drafting Corp so each player is drafting both each round. If you have four players, make sure it goes Runner/Corp/Runner/Corp. Scale appropriately
7. The OP notes that they started by drafting one card for the first pick out of a pack, then started drafting two cards for each pick after that. My friend and I only took one at a time. I don't see a huge functional difference in this. There may just be more of a time commitment when only taking one at a time
8. After the draft, each player should have 55 each of Runner cards and Corp cards
9. You don't get an identity; ignore influence values. Each deck must be at least 45 cards
10. This next part is important, so here's a block quote:

> For the Corp deck, you must obey the Agenda point requirement, so you're allowed to add unlimited copies of Priority Requisition and/or Private Security Force to your deck if you didn't draft enough Agendas during the draft phase. HOWEVER, if you need to add more than three copies of either Priority Requisition or Private Security Force, then you MUST also have at minimum one less copy of the other card in your deck. So, for example, if you want to play with four copies of Private Security Force then you MUST have at least three copies of Priority Requisition in your deck. But you're allowed to play with three Priority Requisition and zero Private Security Force if you drafted enough other Agendas to meet the minimum Agenda Point requirement.

The final step: play with normal rules. Like I said, a friend and I tried this and it worked pretty well. You do lose a lot of the flavor (as some of the comments point out), but the format itself is functional. A comment by Jeff Engel at the bottom of the page offers a decent solution to using identities, we just didn't try it:

> Why not just count up the faction points of what you drafted, whatever you have the most of is your faction.